# Facebook Graph API Search next_page returns empty data object

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently searching through Facebook with the following call from a NodeJS server:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=<query>&access_token=<access_token>&type=event
```

Which returns a data object with 25 events, and some paging information which contains a link to the next page like so:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=<query>&access_token=<access_token>&type=event&after=MDINZ
```

If I open the next page in the browser it shows the next 25 items, with further pages after that, but if I request this next page like I did the first one (from within the server script), it returns an empty data object, and no errors.

Is this a bug on Facebooks end or is there something I'm missing?

I have tried to get the next page data using both npm fb and npm request.

Comment: If you are getting different results in your browser and your script(?) - then it’s probably your script, I’d say.

Comment: Same thing happening to me, even in their api explorer, the next page link returns an empty list

Comment: I have the same with `sharedposts` endpoint. First page contains 1 element and it contains a `next page` but that next page contains  empty `data`

Comment: did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using "npm request" instead of "npm fb", basically just manually construct the url so that I can closer inspect it before sending, then use the next url that is returned in pagination.

```
request('https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=<query>&access_token=<access_token>&type=event', function (error, response, body) {
    var data = JSON.parse(body);    
}
```

Behaviour is like so for anyone else having trouble:

- Results come back with next page under pagination
- Requesting the next page will return more results and more pagination info
- Once no more results are left, the request for next page will return an empty data object